# Datetime in PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I use a PHP script for a banlist that fetches the date and time, but I have an error and don't know how to convert it to "normal" time.

It lists me only the date : 01.01.1970 um 00:00 Uhr

The script part from this:

```
//Convert Epoch Time to Standard format
$datetime = date("d.m.Y \\u\\m H:i \\U\\h\\r", $row['expires']);
echo "<td>$datetime</td>";
```

This is the entry from the mysql db: http://fs1.directupload.net/images/141208/9ugjslm8.jpg

Dont know if it helps?

Have anyone an idea to solve this?

LINK: http://pastebin.com/r0dXg8FX

- The row comes from an plugin. for example: $row['name'] , $row ['banner'], $row['reason'] this comes all from the plugin

Comment: What does your `$row['expires']` contains? `var_dump()` it and see if it's timestamp.

Comment: Are you sure that the row contains an actual date in the database? I think it's probably just zero which is 1970.

Comment: That means `$row['expires']` is a value that is essentially `0`, the start of the UNIX epoch, Jan 1st 1970.

Comment: The row is from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this image](http://fs1.directupload.net/images/141208/9ugjslm8.jpg) (that you have given in deleted answer) you have milliseconds. Divide milliseconds with 1000 to get seconds.

Probably something like this:

```php
$datetime = date('d.m.Y \u\m H:i \U\h\r', $row['expires'] / 1000);
```

But, if you get year 1970, that means that you are on 32bit machine, and your fetched INT is out of range. In this case you could just cut last 3 numbers with string function `substr()`:

```php
$datetime = date('d.m.Y \u\m H:i \U\h\r', substr($row['expires'], 0, -3));
```

Comment: Ok will try this too if im at home :D

Comment: Ok i try it so for now the time is correctly but the date is wrong...?!?! very confused.. now its 11.12.2014 because its 08.12.2014 oO
http://fs1.directupload.net/images/141208/swk8pe2s.jpg

Comment: sry but dont know what exactly do you mean with var_dump($row['expires']); ? The time was insert by an spigot plugin that the time sends to the mysql db

Comment: This? string(13) "1418279542453"

Comment: This timestamp represents `2014-12-11T06:32:22Z`. If this is invalid, then you have wrong timestamp stored in your database.

Comment: this is horrible... how can i solve this? i make nothing on the db... in the game (minecraft) i type for example: /warn nohopeless test | the plugin send this to the db | and i would like to present it on my webpage but what is wrong?... halp :D

Comment: You should probably ask new question. And your English is very bad, I can't understand half of what you are saying. `the plugin send this to the db` probably this is the problem, but I cannot help you without more info.

Comment: Sorry for my english im a german guy :D and can not so good write or speak english :(

Comment: That is no excuse, my native language is also not English :)

Answer (score 3):

> It lists me only the date : **01.01.1970 um 00:00 Uhr**

That simply means you are thinking of `$row['expires']` incorrectly. That is not a UNIX Timestamp value and is producing an invalid date. *It means the value essentially evaluates to 0, which is Jan 1st 1970 in UNIX time*

`date()` requires you to send a valid Unix timestamp to it (INT 11), is that what you have in database for that field? or it is a date time field?

Try this

```
echo date("d.m.Y \\u\\m H:i \\U\\h\\r", "2014-10-12");   //invalid

echo date("d.m.Y \\u\\m H:i \\U\\h\\r", time());  //valid: current unix timestamp
```

Comment: "Default date" is a weird way to put it. It means the value essentially evaluates to `0`, which is Jan 1st 1970 in UNIX time.

Comment: If `$row['expires']` contains any date string then `strtotime($row['expires'])` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date to UNIX timestamp first. Try with -

```
$datetime = date("d.m.Y \\u\\m H:i \\U\\h\\r", strtotime($row['expires']));
echo "<td>$datetime</td>";
```

Comment: I will try this when im at home