# How to convert Date value coming from Web Service to date string in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, json, web-services, date

I am querying some data from MSSQL server using a web service which I have written. I get the values in JSON format. In order to convert data table to json string I use `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` class. I have a date field which is turned into a long integer between the paranthesis.

```
...,"startDate":"\/Date(1387231200000)\/",...
```

When I try to convert this value to date string using `gmdate()` function,

```
$sDate = gmdate("d/m/Y", preg_replace('/\D/','',$jsonArray['startDate']));
```

I get **18/08/1968** result. But the actual value in DB is **17.12.2013 00:00:00**.

I also tried

```
$sDate = gmdate("d/m/Y", "1387231200000");
```

still returns  **18/08/1968**.

Comment: check whether `preg_replace('/\D/','',$jsonArray['startDate'])` is displaying same value as `1387231200000`

Comment: @krishna yes it does.

Comment: If you look at your datetime string and compare it to one generated by PHP `time()` you will see that it is 3 characters too long. However if you remove the last 3 Zeroes you actually get the date `16/12/2013 22:00:00'. Are you sure about the original date on the SQLServer database? Or is there some kind of timezone issue as well?

Comment: @RiggsFolly as you said I removed last three zeros then it is almost OK. If I can change the timezone successfully, it will be done.

Comment: I think a better solution would be to change the server to deliver a DateTime in a more universally understood format. PHP Datetime is based on UNIX EPOCH and I would bet SQL Server is slightly different even though SQLServer started life as Sybase.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Datetime in PHP Script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27356647/67332). Like I already explained in this answer, you are dealing with miliseconds....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have foundt the solution. According to answer here which was deleted I could have got nearly correct value. As [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly) mentioned, date string closes to desired value after deleted last three zeros.

Then I have changed the time zone to `Europe/Istanbul`.

```
$sDate = createDate($jsonArray['startDate']);
```

And the function `createDate()` comes:

```
function createDate($date) {

    $date = preg_replace('/\D/', '', substr($date, 0, -5));

    $desiredDateFormatString = "d/m/Y";

    $inputEpoch = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $date);

    $desiredTimeZoneString = 'Europe/Istanbul';

    $dateTimeObject = new DateTime(date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $inputEpoch));

    $dateTimeObject->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($desiredTimeZoneString));  

    $outputDateTimeString = $dateTimeObject->format($desiredDateFormatString);

    return $outputDateTimeString;
}
```